# how to use update panel(ajax control) in my page for update gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have a scriptmanager in my master page and , my content page has a gridview and btndelete I want when click btndelete delete selected data and refresh the gridview and btndelete is out of update panel
I very try but mycode work very bad please help me :((

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
             BorderColor="Blue" BorderStyle="Solid" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
             ForeColor="Black"  GridLines="Vertical" Width="656px"  >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateField>
                     <ItemTemplate>

                         <asp:CheckBox ID="check1" runat="server" />

                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="picname" HeaderText="picname" SortExpression="picname" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#99FF66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" BorderColor="#006600" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#33CC33" ForeColor="#0066FF" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderStyle="Dashed" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="Lime" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#0066CC" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
        </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btndelete" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="btndelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="btndelete_Click" />
```

this is my cs code for btndelete:

```
 protected void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


                ArrayList mylist = new ArrayList();

                string id = string.Empty;
                 int j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("check1");
                    if (cb != null)
                    {
                        if (cb.Checked)
                        {
                            id = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                            mylist.Add(id);
                            } 

                        }
                    }
                }
                delet(mylist);
}


     private void delet(ArrayList a) {
                SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection();
                con2.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["photogaleryConnectionString"].ToString();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from picture where picname =" + "@picname", con2);




                    foreach (string s in a)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("picname", s.ToString());
                        con2.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con2.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: you should post the code you tried in btndelete_Click

Comment: pls post your cs code ..!

Comment: I post cs code now  :((

Comment: You need to bind the `GridView` with leftovers after `delet(mylist);`.

Comment: I dont bind gridview please say other way :((

Comment: please show a example for this issue